# Multiple hashtable values need to format in a table in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, append

I am trying get computer information for a list of computers and append to a table. Kind of confused how I can take the data from the hashtable and add them to one table. Below is the code of what I have so far.  Any assistance will be appreciated!

```
   $name = Get-Content .\computers.txt


foreach($c in $Name){


$test = Test-Connection -ComputerName $c -Count 1 -Quiet

 if($test -eq $true)
{
 $os = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_operatingsystem -ComputerName  $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $cs = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ComputerName   $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $pr = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_processor   -ComputerName     $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $bs = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios -ComputerName $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $ps = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_processor   -ComputerName     $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
 $us = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_ComputerSystem  -ComputerName $c -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue



 [hashtable]$osProperties = @{
    ‘Model’=$cs.model;
    ‘Manufacturer’=$cs.manufacturer;
    ‘RAM’=$cs.totalphysicalmemory / 1GB -as [int] ; 
    ‘Cores’=$cs.numberoflogicalprocessors;
    ‘SystemType’=$cs.SystemType
    ‘CPU’=$pr.name;
    ‘Serial’=$bs.serialnumber
    ‘OSVersion’=$os.caption;
    'User'=$us.username;
    }



    #$obj = New-Object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property $osProperties | select Manufacturer, Model, Serial, OSVersion, CPU, Cores,  @{name="Ram (GB)";expression={$($_.Ram)}}, User | ft

   }




else{
$c=$Null
}   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To start with, don't run it one computer at a time. You're wasting cycles...

```
$name = Get-Content .\computers.txt
#Get a list of online servers
$online = Test-Connection $name -count 1 -ea 4|% Address
#Define what we want to do on those servers
$ScriptBlock = {
    $os = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_operatingsystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $cs = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_computersystem -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $pr = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_processor -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $bs = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_bios -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    $ps = Get-WmiObject -Class win32_processor -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        ‘Model’=$cs.model;
        ‘Manufacturer’=$cs.manufacturer;
        ‘RAM’=$cs.totalphysicalmemory / 1GB -as [int] ; 
        ‘Cores’=$cs.numberoflogicalprocessors;
        ‘SystemType’=$cs.SystemType
        ‘CPU’=$pr.name;
        ‘Serial’=$bs.serialnumber
        ‘OSVersion’=$os.caption;
        'User'=$cs.username;
    }
}
#Execute the scriptblock on each server, returning results as objects
$Results = Invoke-Command -scriptblock $ScriptBlock -ComputerName $Online
#Display those objects as a table
$Results | FT
```